# "Product detail page" or "product details page"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, programming

As a name for a (web) page that shows detailed information about a product, which of the following is better fitting/correct:

> product details page

or

> product detail page

Or is there an even better name?

Comment: 'Details of product'?

Comment: "Product details page" is more idiomatic.  Regardless of what the language lawyers may rule, "product detail page" leads the reader to believe that only one detail will be revealed.

Comment: If I clicked on the link called **product details page** and then found that there was only a single detail mentioned on that page, I would indeed be surprised. But it wouldn't have anything to do with singular/plural, it would be more like "you dedicated an entire page just to communicate this one thing??"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page is expanding on the description or one part of a product then you would use the second sentence.

If the page is expanding on multiple bits of a product's information or giving details for a variety of products then you would use the first sentence.

Comment: So if the page describes the product with text and picture, and shows product price information, then the *details* form is correct?

Comment: @Qtax - You're spot on.